# Running 2 java programs from 1 eclipse or 2 better?

Tags: java

I am using Indigo Eclipse and want to run 2 java programs . Would it be better if I use my older  eclipse to run it it terms of performance or just run the 2 programs in 1 eclipse ? Or maybe use 2 JREs to run the 2 programs in 1 eclipse ?

Comment: Do you need to run it from Eclipse?

Comment: Is this a 2 java 1 cup question?

Comment: What difference does it make to run in Indigo or the "older" version?

Comment: @MadcoreTom no , would it help much to run it from CMD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to, then don't run it from within either eclipse.  Use the command line to start java and use the -cp argument to set the classpath to include any libraries you need.

If you must run it from eclipse, there is no reason to have two heavy instances of eclipse running just so you can launch a program.  Start them both from the same instance of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can run as many programs from one Eclipse instance as you like.

Answer (score 0):

"In terms of performance" Eclipse is very memory-hungry: I'd choose to use one instance of Eclipse to conserve.